# Can a groom touch the feet of the bride during marriage?

Tags: rituals, marriage

In some hindu marriages I see couples durning the feet touching practice, once the bride bends down, touches the groom's feet and gets back up, the groom then bends down and touches the feet of the bride. The couples call it an act of "Mutual respect" and some media outlets call it "Progressive wedding".
My question: Is the groom touching the bride's feet allowed in Hinduism? Can the groom receive blessings from the bride by touching her feet?

Comment: according to traditional hindu marriage, the groom HAS to touch the bride's feet. but for a different reason entirely. you can read hindu marriage rites for full ritual and explanation. jokingly we say, whatever he is going to do in future, he is practicing now. what you saw is definitely 'progressive'. progress in which direction though is debatable. you're definitely not supposed to prostrate someone younger (rare exceptions), and wife must be at least 1 year younger to groom, so the question of receiving blessing from bride makes no sense according to tradition.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are two views.

1. Husband is the most worshippable deity for his wife. He for her is God.The Patistotra says:

> Namah brahmaswarupaya satipraanapraya cha/
>   Namasyaaya cha pujyaaya hridhadhaaraya te namah//Patir brahma patirvishnur patireva maheswarah/patischa nirgunaadharo tasmai sri pataye namah (Ref: Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 6, page 322-323)
>
> which means that for wife, husband is God. He is worshipable and **Namasya**.He is Brahmaa, Vishnu and Shiva for the wife.

This is our ageold tradition.Wives are not allowed even to utter their husband's name,so revered should be he by her. We know that Swami Vivekananda mentioned, the ideals of the Indian women are Sita, Savitri and Damayanti.They all were very very respecful to their husbands.Devi Sati left Her body when Her father uttered ugly words about Her husband Shiva. The 51 Shaktipeethas are created out of Her body and so each represent the importance of Pati-bhakti in our tradition. Our smritis  say that women need no other spiritual practice . Just serving husband,and in laws will be enough for her.Marriage of the girls is considered equivalent to upanayana of the upper caste boys. So the touching bride's feet to show respect is something unthinkable. (Ref: Jagajjanani Sati-Ramani, Sitaramdas Omkarnath, Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math,Vol.6, page 314 - 323).

2. According to Sri Sri Durga-Saptasati, popularly known as Sri Sri Chandi, all women are forms of the Divine Mother("striyah samasraa sakalaa jagatsu" in mantra 6, chapter 11).So from this viewpoint, all can pay respect to any woman.

Sri Ramakrishna worshipped His wife as the Divine Mother.

But general prescription should be that the husband has to be loving and caring, but touching feet of wife is something odd according to our tradition.

Comment: Can you specify your sources more precisely?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu what type of specification do you exactly want? This is our ageold culture and almost all scriptures have glorified the parivratas. you can check the Vrihatdharmapurana nnd Mahabharat(Parvati's views on this topic) in Danadharma prava(chapter 123) of Anusashana Parva.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu doesn't want sources for himself. it is for all users of this site. without sources, people can start saying random opinions like 'husband should only touch wife's feet not other way around'

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee, what he is asking is to post a link to those sources on internet

Comment: @ram everything not available on net. if they were, such a site would become redundant

Comment: @Partha Banerjee. User ram specified it correctly. It normal on this stackexchange to post online links of your references. Please do it, if it cannot be found please scan your reference and upload it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I have been told by moderator that mentioning book name , author name and page number are enough. So please do not make such requests .

Comment: @ Partha, it is enough indeed but now it is hard for us to check the validiy of your claims. Therefore I shall choose to ignore your post for now.

Comment: Also, I downvoted it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu thanks so much.i am not here to get votes

Comment: You are welcome!